# Why does the filtering of state is not returning data using React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my problem since 2 days ago I don't know what this called but here is the description of my problem.

There is state datas, now I need to filter the datas base on the current date. when I try to console the data without filtering the data is shown. However if I try to filter the data base on the date and try to console it, shows empty array currently using React Js for frontend and backend laravel. I will show you guys the sample current output right now.

Here is the data without filtering

[image: Data]

Here is the data with filter base on the datepicker.

[image: with filter date]

For the sample code:

```
let date_current = new Date();
let year_current = date_current.getFullYear();
let month_current = date_current.getMonth();
let dt_current = date_current.getDate();

let monthsArr = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

if (dt_current < 10) {
    dt_current = '0' + dt_current;
}

let valDate = ""
valDate = monthsArr[month_current] + ' ' + dt_current + ', ' + year_current

let inputTS = Date.parse(valDate)

console.log(filterReceiveChk);

let result = filterReceiveChk.filter(d=>Date.parse(d.checkDate) <= inputTS);

console.log(result);
```

Ex Response:

[image: Response]

Conclusion: If I try to condition if the result has length of 1 it always return false because there is no data on my result.

Comment: What is the format of data of checkDate in filterReceiveChk array. The logic appears to be fine.

Comment: @sasidhar i change my content, please see the Ex. Response

Comment: It doesn't look like your `filterReceiveChk` array has any property by the name checkDate

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Try doing a console log of this statement `console.log(filterReceiveChk.map(d => d.checkDate))`

Comment: if i console that. Mar 20, 2021 , Mar 19, 2021

Comment: try this, `let result = filterReceiveChk.filter(d=>Date.parse(d.checkDate.toString()) <= inputTS);`

Comment: @sasidhar now it works however the only data he got is less than to the date picker

Comment: @sasidhar meaning the equal date is not getting.

Comment: may be that is because when you construct inputTS you are considering the current date, meaning the hours and minutes as well. May be the filterReceiveChk dates has higher hours and minutes.